# Bloom filter design

Tags: algorithm, hash, bloom-filter

I wanted to know where I can find an implementation of the Bloom filter, with some explanation about the choice of the hash functions.

Additionally I have the following questions:
1) the Bloom filter is known to have false positives. Is it possible to reduce them by using two filters, one for used elements, and one for non-used elements (assuming the set is finite and known a-priori) and compare the two?
2) are there other similar algorithms in the CS literature?

Comment: bloom filters are often used when the range of possible elements is very large. One example is to store if a certain query is in a search engine's cache. Thus, in most cases [I know of], you cannot store a filter of "non used elements", since those are infinte.

Comment: true, but I was referring to the case where the set of elements is finite, and known. It may be weird but my application is totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition is that you'll get a better reduction in false positives by using the additional space that the anti-filter would have occupied to just expand the positive filter.

As for resources, the papers referenced for March 8 from [my course syllabus](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/datastructures/schedule.html) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

An Java implementation of the Bloom filter can be found from [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/heaad/archive/2011/01/02/1924195.html). In case you cannot view it, I will paste the code in the following (with comments in Chinese).

```
import java.util.BitSet;

publicclass BloomFilter 
{
    /* BitSet初始分配2^24个bit */ 
    privatestaticfinalint DEFAULT_SIZE =1<<25; 
    /* 不同哈希函数的种子，一般应取质数 */
    privatestaticfinalint[] seeds =newint[] { 5, 7, 11, 13, 31, 37, 61 };
    private BitSet bits =new BitSet(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    /* 哈希函数对象 */ 
    private SimpleHash[] func =new SimpleHash[seeds.length];

    public BloomFilter() 
    {
        for (int i =0; i < seeds.length; i++)
        {
            func[i] =new SimpleHash(DEFAULT_SIZE, seeds[i]);
        }
    }

    // 将字符串标记到bits中
    publicvoid add(String value) 
    {
        for (SimpleHash f : func) 
        {
            bits.set(f.hash(value), true);
        }
    }

    //判断字符串是否已经被bits标记
    publicboolean contains(String value) 
    {
        if (value ==null) 
        {
            returnfalse;
        }
        boolean ret =true;
        for (SimpleHash f : func) 
        {
            ret = ret && bits.get(f.hash(value));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /* 哈希函数类 */
    publicstaticclass SimpleHash 
    {
        privateint cap;
        privateint seed;

        public SimpleHash(int cap, int seed) 
        {
            this.cap = cap;
            this.seed = seed;
        }

        //hash函数，采用简单的加权和hash
        publicint hash(String value) 
        {
            int result =0;
            int len = value.length();
            for (int i =0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                result = seed * result + value.charAt(i);
            }
            return (cap -1) & result;
        }
    }
}
```

In terms of designing Bloom filter, the number of hash functions your bloom filter need can be determined as in [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cao/papers/summary-cache/node8.html) also refering the [Wikipedia article about Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), then you find a section *Probability of false positives*. This section explains how the number of hash functions influences the probabilities of false positives and gives you the formula to determine *k* from the desired expected prob. of false positives.

---

Quote from the Wikipedia article:

> Obviously, the probability of false
>   positives decreases as m (the number
>   of bits in the array) increases, and
>   increases as n (the number of inserted
>   elements) increases. For a given m and
>   n, the value of k (the number of hash
>   functions) that minimizes the
>   probability is
>
> [image: formula]

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to implement a Bloom filter using Java 8 features. You just need a `long[]` to store the bits, and a few hash functions, which you can represent with `ToIntFunction<T>`. I made a brief write up on [doing this from scratch](http://richardstartin.uk/building-a-bloom-filter-from-scratch/).

The part to be careful about is selecting the right bit from the array.

```
public class BloomFilter<T> {

     private final long[] array;
     private final int size;
     private final List<ToIntFunction<T>> hashFunctions;

     public BloomFilter(long[] array, int logicalSize, List<ToIntFunction<T>> hashFunctions) {
         this.array = array;
         this.size = logicalSize;
         this.hashFunctions = hashFunctions;
     }

     public void add(T value) {
         for (ToIntFunction<T> function : hashFunctions) {
              int hash = mapHash(function.applyAsInt(value));
              array[hash >>> 6] |= 1L << hash;
         }
     }

     public boolean mightContain(T value) {
         for (ToIntFunction<T> function : hashFunctions) {
              int hash = mapHash(function.applyAsInt(value));
              if ((array[hash >>> 6] & (1L << hash)) == 0) {
                   return false;
              }
         }
         return true;
    }

    private int mapHash(int hash) {
         return hash & (size - 1);
    }


    public static <T> Builder<T> builder() {
         return new Builder<>();
    }

    public static class Builder<T> {
         private int size;
         private List<ToIntFunction<T>> hashFunctions;

         public Builder<T> withSize(int size) {
             this.size = size;
             return this;
         }

         public Builder<T> withHashFunctions(List<ToIntFunction<T>> hashFunctions) {
              this.hashFunctions = hashFunctions;
              return this;
          }

         public BloomFilter<T> build() {
              return new BloomFilter<>(new long[size >>> 6], size, hashFunctions);
         }
     }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we should look at the application of Bloom Filters, and the secret is in the name, it is a Filter and not a data-structure. It is mostly used for saving resources by checking whether items are not part of a set. If you want to minimize false positives to 0, you will have to insert all the items that aren't apart of the set, since there are no false negatives for a well designed Bloom Filter, except that bloom filter would be gigantic and unpractical, might as well just store the items in a skip-list :) I wrote a simple tutorial on Bloom Filters if anyone is interested.

http://techeffigy.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/bloom-filter-tutorial/